# Trying to construct a linq query with multiple where conditions

Tags: c#, api

I am creating an API and am stucked with something that may seem banal for somebody, so please excuse me for my ignorance. I spent like half a day searching and trying to figure out this. I have table StockTransactions, and my purchase property is a boolean indicating whether I am buying or selling:

```
 public class StockTransaction : BaseEntity
{
    [ForeignKey("Stock")]
    public int StockId { get; set; }
    
    public Stock Stock { get; set; }   

    public string UserId { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public bool Purchase { get; set; }
    public int Resolved { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```

}

I want to extract all the transactions that **at the same time** a) have the same email b) relate to buying where quantity is not the same as resolved and c) all the transactions that relate to selling and where date is greater then some indicated date. Here is my code, I have tried different approaches, but all I get in the postman is an empty array, because I don't know how to tell linq - give me at the same time all this, not just filter after filter:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<StockTransaction>> Again(string email)
    {
        var datesy = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

        var list = await (from t in _context.StockTransactions
                   where t.Email == email
                   select t).ToListAsync();

        var list1 = (from s in list
                    where s.Purchase == true && s.Quantity != s.Resolved
                    where s.Purchase != true && s.Date > datesy
                    select s).ToList();

        return await Task.FromResult(list1);
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<StockTransaction>> Fifo(string email)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

        var list = await  _context.StockTransactions.Where(o => (o.Email ==
        email)).ToListAsync();

        list = list.Where((o => (o.Purchase == true && o.Quantity != 
        o.Resolved) && (
        o.Purchase == false && o.Date > today))).ToList();

        return await Task.FromResult(list);
    }
```

And this:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<StockTransaction>> Fifo1(string email)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2); 

        var list = await  _context.StockTransactions.Where(o => (o.Email ==   
        email)).ToListAsync();
        list = list.Where(o => o.Purchase == true && o.Quantity != 
        o.Resolved).ToList();

        return await Task.FromResult(list);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for everybody willing to help...

Comment: All chained Where are the same as using a logical AND operator (&&) instead. Why using ToList between?

Comment: Try using an OR condition instead of an AND. You want to include a row if it meets criteria 1 OR meets criteria 2 OR meets criteria 3. No records meet all three criteria, which is why you currently get back an empty list.

Comment: yes, it was that, I should have used ||, thanks!

Comment: Also, if you want to `var lst1=cntx.Something.Where(x=>Whatever(x))` and then do another LINQ operation on `lst1` and maybe do another, do realized the results until you are finished (with `.ToList` or `.ToListAsync`). If you do several chained LINQ operations, and they are all translatable to SQL, the can be use to compose a final single query

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<StockTransaction>>   
 Fifo5(string email)    
{
        var today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);

        var list = await  _context.StockTransactions.Where(o  
        => o.Email == email && 
        (o.Purchase == true && o.Quantity != o.Resolved) || (
        o.Purchase == false && o.Date >  
        today)).ToListAsync();
        return await Task.FromResult(list);
    }
```